# ruby 1.9.3 build in sublime text 2

Tags: ruby, sublimetext2

I'm searching for a correct .sublime-build for ruby 1.9.3
so far i'm not been able to use gems with the ones i tried

a way to launch my .rb file with the terminal with a shortcut from ST2 should be great for me to

thank you

Comment: How do you have ruby installed? rvm?

Comment: yes i've installed it with rvm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two possible ways, one involves editing the exec.py file that comes with ST2 so that the build process is not piped/captured but i had no luck in this, maybe someone with a python background can ?

The other method works for me, i edit the "c:\users\user\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 2\Packages\Ruby\Ruby.sublime-build" file that also comes with ST2 and change the contents to this.
I have no problem to use gems that are installed correctly like this.

```
{
  "cmd": ["ruby", "$file"],
  "shell": true,
  "file_regex": "^(...*?):([0-9]*):?([0-9]*)",
  "selector": "source.ruby, source.rb, source.rbw",
  "variants":
  [
    {
      "name": "Run",
      "cmd": ["start", "ruby", "$file"],
      "selector": "source.ruby, source.rb, source.rbw"
    }
  ]
}
```

After that you can run Ruby scripts in two ways, the normal one with F7 and in the console with Ctrl-Shift-B (from Build). In order to avoid that the window closes after execution you need to end your script with a system 'pause'. In begin/rescue blocks it would also be best to put this command.

So a script would look like this

```
puts "test"
system 'pause'
```

EDIT: add the option "Open Command Window Here.." to the context-menu

First create and put the following in the file

```
c:\users\user\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 2 \Packages\User\opencommand.py
import sublime, sublime_plugin
import subprocess
import os

class OpenPromptCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit):
        dire = os.path.dirname(self.view.file_name())
        retcode = subprocess.Popen(["cmd", "/K", "cd", dire])

    def is_enabled(self):
        return self.view.file_name() and len(self.view.file_name()) > 0
```

Then open C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 2\Packages\Default\Context.sublime-menu and at the end add

```
{ "caption": "-", "id": "file" },
{ "command": "open_prompt", "caption": "Open Command Window Here…" },
{ "command": "open_dir", "caption": "Open Containing Folder…" },
{ "caption": "-", "id": "end" }
```

From now on you can right-click in a open script and open explorer or the command prompt in the folder where the script is saved.

Comment: is it suppose to open a terminal window when cmd/B ? can't see anything... build looks successful in ST2 console but doesn't print anything (i'm on OSX Lion)

Comment: Ctrl-Shift-B , not cmd/B which is the same as F7 i suppose, try with Cmd-Shift-B, anyway start is for windows, it starts a command-processor in a asynchronous separate window/process, i don't know the equivalent for OSX, sorry

Answer (score 0):

in macOS the equivalent to windows `start` is `open`... ie:

**Windows**

`start .` (opens windows explorer at current path)

**Mac**

`open .` (opens finder at current path)